# ui-router preventDefault() ends in empty view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular-ui-router

i have a section in my angular app that requires the user to be logged in and have a certain level or rights (500 for editor, 1000 for admin)

those requirements are written in the state config like this:

```
    .state('posts.edit', {
        url: '/edit/{id:int}',
        resolve: {
            post: ['$stateParams', 'Post', function($stateParams, Post){
                return Post.findOne($stateParams.id);
            }]
        },
        controller: 'postEditCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/partials/posts/edit.html',
        requiresRight: 500
    })
    .state('admin',{
        url: '/admin',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/partials/admin/dashboard.html',
        requiresRight: 1000
    });
```

then, in my .run i have an event listener for $stateChangeStart that is supposed to block the state off if the user is not authorized. 
code:

```
site.run(["$rootScope", "$timeout", "$state", function($rootScope, $timeout, $state){

$rootScope.state = {
    user: false
}
$rootScope.isAdmin = function(){
    if($rootScope.state.user && $rootScope.state.user.rights >= 1000){
        return true
    }
    else return false;
}
$rootScope.isEditor = function(){
    if($rootScope.state.user && $rootScope.state.user.rights >= 500){
        return true
    }
    else return false;
}


$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
    if(toState.requiresRight){
        if(!$rootScope.state.user || toState.requiresRight > $rootScope.state.user.rights){
            console.log("needed",toState.requiresRight)
            console.log("have", $rootScope.state.user?$rootScope.state.user.rights:false);
            event.preventDefault();
            // $state.go("login");
        }
    }

})
```

}])

when i test if however, my state change is not rejected, but i get an empty view. additionally my sidebar buttons that contain an ng-if (logout, admin link) get shown for a few ms.

i tried it in a plunkr, but couldn't replicate it: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/jOnR2F2pLx4xboDBZtgc)

Comment: Your plnkr code is significantly different from what you've posted. In OP you define `$rootScope.state.user` as a primitive type (boolean) but in `$staeteChangeStart` reference `$rootScope.state.user.rights`. You're probably getting an exception there

Comment: user is set to false if he's not authed. i avoid the exception with the `!$rootScope.state.user` check. having it set to false makes checking a bit nicer to work with. angular also didn't throw me anything. it just went its way

Comment: _i tried it in a plunkr, but couldn't replicate it_ well at least you're at a good starting point. You can start modifying your two apps (one with an issue another in plunker) to make them identical step by step. At the point when you either reproduce in plunker or the issue disappears on base project, you will get a clear point where behavior becomes unexpected